# Lazy loading not workin in my angular cmponent

Tags: angular, lazy-loading, masonry

```
<ngx-masonry class="menu-card-main" [options]="myOptions" [ordered]="true">
  <mat-card ngxMasonryItem class="masonry-item menu-card" *ngFor="let item of menuItems;let i=index" [item]="item" [index]="i" >
    <mat-card-content (click)="openDetailsDialog(item)">
      <img mat-card-image src="assets/dum_images/{{item.image}}" >
      <mat-card-title>{{item.title}}</mat-card-title>
      <p class="text">{{item.desc}}</p>
      <strong>Price: {{currencySymb}} {{item.price}}</strong>
    </mat-card-content>
    <div class="quantityMenu">
      <app-quantity-buttons [item]="item" [index]="i"></app-quantity-buttons>
    </div>
  </mat-card>
</ngx-masonry>
```

`your text`
this is one of my component body. In this case lazyloading is not working.

help me to add lazyloading property on this code.

Routing Module

```
    import { NgModule } from '@angular/core'; 
    import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router'; 
    import { SplashScreenComponent } from './splash-screen/splash-screen.component'; 
    import { MainScreenComponent } from './main-screen/main-screen.component';
    
     const routes: Routes = 
     [ 
       {path:'home',component:MainScreenComponent}, 
       {path:'splash-screen',component:SplashScreenComponent},
       {path:'',pathMatch:'full',redirectTo:'/home'} 
     ]; 
    
    @NgModule({ 
      imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)], 
      exports: [RouterModule] 
    }) 
    export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Comment: Hi @shan khalam, the lazy load phenomen happens on routing module n learn more about it https://angular.io/guide/lazy-loading-ngmodules!

Comment: Please share your routing module

Comment: 'import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { SplashScreenComponent } from './splash-screen/splash-screen.component';
import { MainScreenComponent } from './main-screen/main-screen.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {path:'home',component:MainScreenComponent},
  {path:'splash-screen',component:SplashScreenComponent},
  {path:'',pathMatch:'full',redirectTo:'/home'}
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }'

Comment: There is no lazy loading module - Edit your question with Lazy load modules / components